# Want to convert this .htaccess rule into nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I am new to nginx and really don't have any idea how to do this. What this below code essentially does in htaccess is for example

if a browser requests this css file from this web address

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/css/style-30493094.css
```

then it shows this file

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/css/style.css
```

Same goes for all other defined extensions in this code. css, js, png, jpg, gif
Like if a browser requests this js file from this web address

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/js/javascript-2938293.js
```

then it shows this file

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/js/javascript.js
```

Actually I am trying to accomplish this. http://derek.io/blog/2009/auto-versioning-javascript-and-css-files/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/(css|js|images)/([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ /folder1/$1/$2.$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite
It looks like you can take your current regex and use it in nginx.conf.

```
rewrite ^folder1/(css|js|images)/([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ /folder1/$1/$2.$4 last;
```

So your whole server block might look like:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.0.1;
    server_name blah.blah.com;

    location ~ \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif) {
        rewrite ^folder1/(css|js|images)/([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ /folder1/$1/$2.$4 last;
    }
}
```

EDIT: You'd just have to adjust the regular expression appropriately. 
In your supplied case:

```
rewrite ^(.*/?)([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ /$1$2.$4 last;
```

Which will rewrite:

```
[Anything with an optional trailing slash (or nothing)] followed by [at least one alphabetic character (lowercase only)] followed by [a hyphen] followed by [at least one numeric character] followed by [a dot] followed by [one of css|js|png|jpg|gif]
```

with

```
[That first optional text followed by an optional slash][the alphabetic part (i.e. style)].[the final css|js|png|jpg|gif]
```

Comment: That was fast. Thank you for the solution and although I have not tested above but I want to extend it a little further and want to know if there is a way to apply this to any file regardless of path and folder. I mean if there is a file at /style-9389289.css or file in folder/style-9389289.css